# How do I search a string for multiple strings, and then replace them with other strings? (Python)

Tags: python, string, replace

I have the following sentence "the man went to the shop" and I want to replace any word that has "th" or "sh" with "dogs. The results should look something like this:

dogse man went to dogse dogsop

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
sentence = "the man went to the shop"

to_be_replaced = ["th", "sh"]
replaced_with = "dogs"

for terms in to_be_replaced:
    if terms in sentence:
        new_sentence = sentence.replace(terms,replaced_with)
        print new_sentence
```

Currently, this prints:

```
dogse man went to dogse shop
the man went to the dogsop
```

I want it to print this only:

```
dogse man went to dogse dogsop
```

I would I go about doing this?

Comment: Not the best implementation, but it will work if you re-bind to `sentence`; change `new_sentence` to `sentence`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to work on the same string from the start and keep working on it. You don't need your new_sentence (except if you want to keep the first).

This code should work :

```
sentence = "the man went to the shop"

to_be_replaced = ["th", "sh"]
replaced_with = "dogs"

for terms in to_be_replaced:
    if terms in sentence:
        sentence = sentence.replace(terms,replaced_with)
print sentence
```

It should print :

```
dogse man went to dogse dogsop
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
s.replace("th", "dogs").replace("sh", "dogs")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

text = "the man went to the shop"
repalceed = re.sub(r'sh|th', 'dogs', text)
print(repalceed)
```

out:

```
dogse man went to dogse dogsop
```